# Spring transaction rolled back on RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a transactional method and I'd like to call an other method which may throw a RuntimeException.

The problem is that the transaction gets marked as rollbackOnly when the exception is thrown.

The other method call itself is in a try-catch block, but I think the transaction gets marked when the other method returns by throwing an exception.

**Example:**

*MyService.java*

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyUtils utils;

    @Autowired
    private MyCrudRepository repository;

    @Transactional
    public void publicMethod() {
       try {
           utils.otherPublicMethod();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }

       // RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
       // Even though I caught the exception from the method call itself
       repository.save(new MyEntity());
    }
}
```

*MyUtils.java*

```
@Component
public class MyUtils {

    // Does not use transactions, repositories
    // But I think it inherits the transaction and marks it as rollbackOnly
    public void otherPublicMethod() {

        // Maybe this is seen as an uncaught exception
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I don't think this is a duplicate of [Does Specifying @Transactional rollbackFor Also Include RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830364/does-specifying-transactional-rollbackfor-also-include-runtimeexception), because the exception is eventually caught.
The problem may be similar, as it also involves transactions and rollbacks.

Comment: Spring transaction not depend on line flow it's depends on methods of like if you have any exception inside current method it will rollback

Comment: There must be something going on outside the `try`-`catch` block. Put a log statement in the very end...see if that's getting logged — at the same time you see the rollback.

Comment: Agreed, something doesn't smell right.  That code should work as you want it to.

Comment: @ChristianMüller nah, `RuntimeException` will be caught by `try-catch` as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't think this is a duplicate of the marked question, please see my edit.

Comment: You may be right. I have reopened it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation `@Transactional` has parameters such as `rollbackFor` and `no-rollback-for` with which you can say which exceptions will cause or will not cause rollback. For instance you can write:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class})
```

Which will cause rollback upon `RuntimeException`. However, I believe that `RuntimeException` causes rollback by default. So you probably have to specify this exception in `no-rollback-for` clause.
For details see [Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) and look for "**16.5.5  settings**" paragraph

Comment: Setting a `noRollBackFor` value for the `@Transactional` annotation on the method would mean it never rolls back on a `RuntimeException`. What I would like to do is to roll back only on a _really_ uncaught `RuntimeException`.

Comment: If you catch your exception within method marked @Transactional then that exception should not influence your transactional behavior. there must be other exception somewhere in your method that you didn't catch